# average of a function with respect to its initial values

Tags: calculus, statistics

I have a function, $\langle f(x,y)\rangle$ $x_0,y_0$.  where $x$ and $y$ are row vectors and $x_0,y_0$ are the initial row vector values. Now I would like to know the exact evaluation of the function which is said to be average with respect to the initial values. I have two options which are mentioned below:

1. $f(x-x_0,y-y_0)$/(number of elements) and
2. $(f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0))$/(number of elements)

So which is the right option for the above mentioned case?

Comment: Where you wrote <$f(x,y)$>, did you mean $\langle f(x,y)\rangle\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Yes.. @ Michael